Jupyterlab でローカルのファイルを参照したい
docker-composeファイルを使って作ったjupyterlabNote book でpython3を使用し始めたところです。
画像解析に用いたく、jupyterLab 上にアップロードした画像が読み込めることは確認しました。
ローカルに保存した画像を読み込みたいのですが、読み込めず、以下のコマンドで試してもディレクトリは認識されませんでした。
import os
os.chdir(r'file path')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file path'

ディレクトリを指定したらローカルのファイルが読み込めると書かれているサイトもあるのですが、アップロードしたファイルしか読み込めないと書かれているサイトもあります。
ローカルのファイルを読み込む方法があれば教えていただけると幸いです。
参考url
https://life100create.com/jupyter-notebook-open-file/#toc2

先にカレントディレクトリが何処になっているかを確かめてみてはどうでしょう？ Pythonでカレントディレクトリを取得、変更（移動）

スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ! 質問にあたっては「ヘルプセンター」の質問にあたって 辺りに目を通しておくとよいかも。
質問者さんにとって目の前の事象を述べてるのかもだけど, 第三者にとって何が・どうなってるか, は伝わりにくいものです。 /
① JupyterLab, Jupyter Notebook のどちらを使ってますか？(すぐに区別の必要はないが念の為)
② JupyterLab(？)は Docker上のコンテナーで動かしてますか？
③ 「jupyterLab 上にアップロードした画像」とは何を指してますか？(もしかして docker cp, それともネットからダウンロード？)
④ 'file path' は実際のパスを表してますか？ それとも普通の文字列の 'file path'？
/
仮に Dockerの JupyterLabコンテナーでローカルファイルに直にアクセスのつもりなら, たぶんマウントの必要があるでしょう

併せてこちらと組み合わせればカレントディレクトリにどんなファイル・フォルダがあるか分かるでしょう。Pythonでファイル名・ディレクトリ名の一覧をリストで取得

アドバイスをいただき、まことにありがとうございます
返信が誠におそくなり、申し訳ございません
①　JupyterLab　を使用しています
②　 Docker コンテナ内で動作しています　
使用しているDocker イメージは ken2s/jupyterlab　https://qiita.com/ken2s/items/8784576d4f22432c4270　です
③　「jupyterLab 上にアップロードした画像」とは　JupyterLab の左側にあるファイルブラウザを使い、ローカルマシンから画像ファイルを ドラッグ＆ドロップ してコンテナ内にコピーした画像のことです。
jupyterlab 内のターミナルにおいて
$ ls /notebooks
10001.tiff　というように表示されます
④ 'file path' は実際のパスです
ご助言に従い、docker-compose.yml  に
volumes:

/mnt/c/Users/name/Downloads:/notebooks　と書き、マウントを試みましたが、うまくいきませんでした

os.getcwd()で取得できる現在のディレクトリは/notebooksです
ご回答いただいたにも関わらず返信しておらず大変申し訳ございません
